# Rest assured - verify url of last page after many redirects

Tags: spock, rest-assured

I have flow of many redirects (oauth2 + other stuff) and what I would like to verify is: How do I get url of page after last redirect? I get 200 status code and can see in logs that I'm getting to right page, but cannot verify that in code itself. Something like this:

```
given()
            .port(serverPort)
            .redirects().follow(true)
            .expect().statusCode(200)
            .url("http://myexpectedurlafterlastredirect") <- no method to verify it
            .when()
            .get(path)
```

any suggestions?

Comment: There's no explicit way to check for the URL I suppose, where do you expect to see the URL ? in the header or the response of the body of the response ?

Comment: well I don't know where to expect it ;) with just one redirect I could easily turn follow redirects of and fetch it from 'Location' header, but with more redirects its not convenient - to say at least. It's just some kind of surprise for me we are not able to verify where we are at the end.

Comment: Interesting, I never got a requirement as such so wouldn't be sure. Let me know if you come across any open sites that are available with redirection and I"ll try my luck using Rest Assured